# Database Normalization - I think?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, normalization

We have a J2EE content management and e-commerce system, and in this system – for sake of a simple example – let’s say that we have 100 objects.  All of these objects extend the same base class, and all share many of the same fields.

Let’s take two objects as an example: a news item that would be posted on a website, and a product that would be sold on a website.  Both of these share common properties:

- IDs: id, client ID, parent ID (long)
- Flags: deleted, archived, inactive (boolean)
- Dates: created, modified, deleted (datetime)
- Content: name, description

And of course they have some properties that are different:

- News item: author, posting date
- Product: price, tax

So (finally) here is my question.  Let’s say we have 100 objects in our system, and they all follow this pattern.  They have many fields that overlap, and some unique fields.  In terms of a relational database, would we be better off with:

*Option One: Less Tables, Common Tables*

- table_id: id, client ID, parent ID (long) (id is the primary key, a GUID for all objects)
- table_flag: id, deleted, archived, inactive (boolean)
- table_date: id, created, modified, deleted (datetime)
- table_content: id, name, description
- table_news: id, author, posting date
- table_product: id, price, tax

*Option Two: More Tables, Common Fields Repeated*

- table_news: id, client ID, parent ID, deleted, archived, inactive, name, description, author, posting date
- table_product: id, client ID, parent ID, deleted, archived, inactive, name, description, price, tax

For full disclosure – I am a developer and not a DBA, and because of that I prefer option one.   But there is another team member that prefers option two, and I think he makes valid points.

*Option One: Pros and Cons*

- Pro: Encapsulates common fields into common tables.
- Pro: Need to change a common field?  Change it in one place.
- Pro: Only creates new fields/tables when they are needed.
- Pro: Easier to create the queries dynamically, less repetitive code
- Con: More joining to create objects (not sure of DB impact on that)
- Con: More complex queries to store objects (not sure of DB impact on that)
- Con: Common tables will become huge over time

*Option Two: Pros and Cons*

- Pro: Perhaps it is better to distribute the load of all objects across tables?
- Pro: Could index the news table on the client ID, and index the product table on the parent ID.
- Pro: More readable to human eye: easy to see all the fields for an object in one table.

My Two Cents

For me, I much prefer the elegance of the first option – but maybe that is me trying to force object oriented patterns on a relational database.  If all things were equal, I would go with option one UNLESS a DB expert told me that when we have millions of objects in the system, option one is going to create a performance problem.

Apologies for the long winded question.  I am not great with DB lingo, so I probably could have summarized this more succinctly if I better understood terms like normalization.  I tried to search for answers on this topic, and while I found many that were close (I suspect this is a common DB issue) I could not find any that answered all my questions.  I read through [this article](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/database_normalization_process.html) on normalization:

But I did not totally understand it.  On the one hand it was saying that you should remove any redundancies.  But on the other hand, it was saying that each attribute should define only one object.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 2):

You should read [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) by Martin Fowler.  He writes about several options for the scenario you describe:

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html): One table for all object subtypes. Stores all attributes, setting them NULL where they are inapplicable to the row's object subtype.
- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html): One table for column common to all subtypes, then one table for each subtype to store subtype-specific columns.
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html): One table for each subtype, storing both subtype-specific columns and columns common to all subtypes.
- [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html): One table for all object subtypes.  Store common attributes as conventional columns, but combine optional or subtype-specific columns as fields in a BLOB that stores XML or JSON or whatever format you want.

Each one of these designs has pros and cons, so choose a solution depending on the most common way you access your data.

However, notice I use the word *subtype* above.  I would use these designs only if the different object types are subtypes of a common base class.  I'm assuming that `News item` and `Product` don't actually share a logical base class (besides `Object`); they are not subtypes of a common superclass.

So for the sake of OO design, I would choose Concrete Table Inheritance.  This avoids any inappropriate coupling between these subtypes.  There are columns the two tables have in common, but they basically amount to bookkeeping, not anything to do with the function of the class and hence the table.

Comment: Hi Bill,  I must have written my question a bit better than I thought, because your answer is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.  And you are right - in fact the inheritance chain for my example would look more like this:

* SuperObject
* ContentObject extends SuperObject
* NewsItem extends ContentObject
* BuyableObject extends SuperObject
* ProductObject extends BuyableObject

That's the gist.  So I would have the tables with fields common for ALL objects, and then the tables for fields common to ContentObjects, and then if necessary a table for fields for NewsItem.

Comment: But my follow up question would be - is there a performance hit for putting all that common info in common tables?

Comment: No.  You'd have to store it for each news/product row anyway, so you end up with the same number of rows.  If anything, it helps you to reduce the need for JOINing tables together when you need all attributes of a Product or of a News item.